# how can i make the google maps bubble longer in height?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i want to be able to put more information into the bubble so maybe making it dynamically longer based on the content that is inserted into it.

thanks

Comment: You question needs more information about what you are doing / want to do. I used to put plain HTML into the Google Maps Bubble and it always resized dynamically to the size of its content.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common problem that Google Maps developers encounter.  The answers in the following question cover the various solutions:

[How to set Google map's marker's infowindow max height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919659/how-to-set-google-maps-markers-infowindow-max-height)

To summarize:

- You need to set the height attribute on images.
- You need to make sure your infoWindow HTML elements are not inheriting any CSS styles from the document that change their height.