# How to make my Google Maps overlays taller (in Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm trying to put my friend's restaurant reviews on a map (see the prototype at http://eatrichly.heroku.com/). The idea is that when you click a marker, you should see the review of the restaurant. Unfortunately, the popup that appears when you click a marker occasionally isn't tall enough to accommodate the corresponding review. E.g.:

[alt text http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/3396/picture4mfy.png](http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/3396/picture4mfy.png)

**Here is my code:**

In the controller:

```
  def index
    @reviews = Review.all
    @map = GMap.new('map')
    @map.control_init(:large_map => true, :map_type => false)
    @map.center_zoom_init([Address.first.lat,Address.first.lng], 13)

    Restaurant.all.each do |r|
      body = %{
        <b><a target="_BLANK" href="#{r.menu_link}">#{r.name}</a></b> (#{r.cuisines.first})
        <br><br>
        #{r.review.body}
      }

      marker = GMarker.new([r.addresses.first.lat, r.addresses.first.lng],
      :title => r.name,
      :info_window => body.strip)
      @map.overlay_init(marker)
    end
```

In the view:

```
<%= GMap.header %>
<%= @map.to_html %>
<%= @map.div(:width => 1024, :height => 1000) %>
```

How can I make the info windows fit the text they contain?

Comment: I noticed that you still have this problem on your page. Try my answer - it works guaranteed - or your money back!

Comment: It's been a busy week, but I'm going to try your answer as soon as I have some spare time (I have a real job too!)

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty common problem that Google Maps developers encounter.  The answers in the following question cover the various solutions:

[How to set Google map's marker's infowindow max height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919659/how-to-set-google-maps-markers-infowindow-max-height)

To summarize:

- You need to set the height attribute on images (not applicable in this case).
- You need to make sure your infoWindow HTML elements are not inheriting any CSS styles from the document that change their height ([Inherited CSS problem](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/css.htm))

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Cannonade's suggestions.  However, after looking at your code and noticing that the problem still remained after deleting all the styles, I found the problem elsewhere:

**You need to set a [maxWidth](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindowOptions.maxWidth) on your info windows.**  Right now GInfoWindowOptions is blank: `{}`.  Try changing it to: `{maxWidth:400}`.

Here's what I think is happening: since you don't have a maxWidth, Google Maps decides that the window doesn't need to be very tall, since your content will just go on horizontally.  However, in practice the info window really does have a maximum width - but it's not factored into the initial calculation, so your text ends up overflowing.

Comment: Thanks Chris,  this is something that I wasn't aware of.  I'll add it to my checklist of things to look at when my infoWindows don't work ;).