# Set height of Google Map InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to create an InfoWindow on a Google Map using the V3 Javascript API, the window needs a fixed size, and no scrollbars. The window I'm getting automatically gets a height that I cannot seem to override.

There are numerous posts here on SO with answers suggesting setting the height of

```
.gm-style-iw{
     height:something!important;
}
```

or passing the height in as a constructor argument

```
new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<my custom markup>',
    height : 500
});
```

or setting the height of my custom content to which the window wrapper will automatically adjust, but these aren't working : the gm-style-iw element and my own content get their proper height, but the window wrapper ignores the size of its content and makes its content scrollable. Suppressing scrollbars is not viable, I need the window to be large enough for scrollbars to be unnecessary.

After examining the infowindow structure, it seems to consist of an outer border that's painted onto the canvas, some inner wrappers with overflow:auto; that prevent spillover, and then the custom content we can inject into the window. The outer content is controlled by some Google script, live. I can see changes I make in-browser being undone, and the tricks like forcing an InfoWindow redraw always leads back to the same incorrect size.

How can I accurately adjust the size of the wrapping window?

Comment: you can target target the element via CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making your map itself bigger?

There are also some great questions on here that have similar questions to yours you may want to look at the related sidebar ->

Here's one that seems like it may work for you:
[How to set a specific height for Google Maps infowindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485715/how-to-set-a-specific-height-for-google-maps-infowindow?rq=1)

Hope this helps! Best of luck!

Comment: Making the map larger "fixed" this - no amount of CSS hacking or overriding can change window size if the map isn't large enough. Pity this isn't officially documented.