# Google Map .InfoWindow Set Height and Width

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How do you set the size and width of a google map `InfoWindow`? I looked [on the api page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) and only found a `maxWidth` method.

**Edit:** I have tried a few things. So far none of these work:

```
    var markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: markerHTMLString,
        maxHeight: 400,  //Doesn't work
        maxWidth: 400,   //Doesn't work
        width: 300,      //Doesn't work
        height: 300      //Doesn't work
    });
```

Also say `markerHTMLString` is equal to this:

```
<div class = "MarkerPopUp"><div class = "MarkerContext">Text</div></div>
```

I have tried these three options as well (none of them worked)

1. ```
   .MarkerPopUp {
       height: 300px;
       width: 300px;
   }
   ```
2. ```
   .MarkerPopUp {
       height: 300px;
       width: 300px;
   }

   .MarkerContext {
       height: 300px;
       width: 300px;
   }
   ```
3. ```
   .MarkerContext {
       height: 300px;
       width: 300px;
   }
   ```

This also will not work:

```
document.getElementById('MarkerPopUp')parentNode.style.overflow = '';
```

or this

```
document.getElementById('MarkerPopUp').parentNode.parentNode.style.overflow = '';
```

I am pretty much going through every thread I can find and trying everything. Just to limit a few things out (though there may be another issue)

Comment: You can use CSS, inline CSS or JS modification. Summarized some solutions in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610923/4378314

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It may be that when the html is passed into the map api and parsed out that it doesn't have access to your stylesheet delcarations.  Try adding your width as inline style on MarkerPopUp.

```
<div class = "MarkerPopUp" style="width: 300px;"><div class = "MarkerContext">Text</div></div>
```

I know, I hate inline styles too, but it could solve your issue in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wrapper `<div>` and add style like this `<div style='height: 40px; text-align: center'>` and add css code `.gm-style-iw {  max-width: 400px!important;}` in your css file;

Answer (score 0):

```
.gm-style-iw{
    max-height: 10px;
}
```

Setting style for gm-style-iw does the work!

Answer (score 0):

Use !important in css

```
.MarkerPopUp {
    height: 300px !important;
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try following code:

```
 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "",
        maxWidth: 200 ,
        maxHeight: 400
    });
```

Comment: The "maxHeight" property isn't supported.