# Customising the google map info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm struggling to change the size of the infoWindow on google maps apiv3. I've been looking at the documentation here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max

But I can't seem to change the width and the height of the infoWidow. I would like to be able to just remove the scroll bar that it adds when the content is to large for the default window. To do this I'm going give the window a fixed height and width. Which for some reason isn't working as it should.

Here is my JS for google maps:

```
var map;
var bounds;
var infowindow;
var markersArray = [];
var data;
var image = '/img/markers/google_icon.png';

function initialize() {
  console.log("Map Initialised");
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.8382,-2.327815);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps-canvas-xx'), mapOptions);
  bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}
function clearOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray = [];
}

function getMarker(event) {
   console.log("Lookup requested.");
   $('#code_search').text($('#PostcodePostcode').val());
   $('#address_search').show('slow');
  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();
  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
      var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
      url = "http://weburl/location/a/",
      $.ajax({
        crossDomain:true, 
        dataType: "jsonp",
    url: url,
    data : form_data,
    success: function ( data ) {
        clearOverlays();
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.locations.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.locations[i].lat,data.locations[i].lng); 
        var contentString =  '<div id="infoWrap"><p>' + data.locations[i].name + '</p>' +
                 '<p style="font-size:8pt;">' + data.locations[i].address.replace(/,/g,',<br>') + '<br>' + data.locations[i].post_code  + '<br>' + 
                 data.locations[i].phone + '<br>' + '<a target="_blank" href="' + data.locations[i].url + '">' + data.locations[i].url + '</p></div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString,
                  });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: latlng,
                    title:data.locations[i].name,
            info: infowindow,
            content: contentString,
            icon: image,
            });



        bounds.extend(latlng);
        markersArray.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            marker.info.setContent(this.content);
            marker.info.open(map, this);
        });

            }//close each
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried adding this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString,
            width: "800px",
                  });
```

But I can't seem to change the width and height of the infoWindow. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map .InfoWindow Set Height and Width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858898/google-map-infowindow-set-height-and-width)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no width property in the [InfoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) object, just a maxWidth.  To set the size use normal css on the HTML markup in the contentString.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: '<div style="height:200px; width: 800px;">'+ contentString+'</div>';
    });
```

Comment: Thanks you! I was doing what you've done above but it turns out it had to be an inline style. Rather than setting a div with a class or ID. Thanks again.